# Draw on Price From Indicator Pane

Tags: line, pine-script

How can I draw a Line in the Price Bar Pane/Window from an Indicator that is in its own Pane/Window.  Think drawing a Line on the Price Bars from a MACD Indicator.

if this is the Line struct:

```
line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, xloc, extend, color, style, width) → series line
```

then how do I do it?

What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Based on this answer, it's not possible in this version of Pine Script (V5). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72500088/how-to-draw-both-on-the-pane-and-the-chart-in-the-same-indicator-v5?noredirect=1#comment128072840_72500088