# How to draw both on the Pane and the Chart in the same indicator? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In the `indicator()` header, we can specify where do we want to draw (using the `overlay=true` attribute): the chart or the pane. **How to tell the script which drawing/label/plotchar etc. to display on which area?**

For example:

```
plot(Something) // on the pane
label.new(SomethingElse) // on the chart
```

Or can we define separate indicator sections with different `overlay` parameters?

Comment: This cannot be done in Pine currently afaik.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen That is correct so you can convert your comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this cannot be done in Pine.
A script only pertains to a single pane.